# Adding values form array to a mathematical function

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, equation

Hi I have a function y=x^2 how to add valuesd from array. if x is going from 1 to 10.

```
x= 1:1:10;
 array=[3 4 5 1 5 4 3 2 4 1];
 y=x.^2 + array;
```

so if x is 1 add 3 from array  if x is 2 add 4 and so on?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? It works perfectly doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with that you have?

```
x = 1:10;
array = [3 4 5 1 5 4 3 2 4 1];
y = x.^2 + array
y =
     4     8    14    17    30    40    52    66    85   101
```

or is this what you want?

```
y2 = [x + array].^2
y2 =
    16    36    64    25   100   100   100   100   169   121
```